# See folder size updated in real-time

Tags: windows

I've searched the whole internet but couldn't find a answer. Is there any way/software to see folder size updated in real-time? I can't just leave the "properties" window open as it doesn't update in real-time.

Comment: So far as I can see, that is the way NTFS works, so you will need to check the folder size properties as you need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is: *yes, there is*.

Probably there are many other solutions up there on the Internet, but by installing the *Cygwin* Software Environment, you will eventually write them yourself.

So, just perform the following steps:

**1.** Install the *Cygwin* Software Environment by reading this [Software Installation Procedure](https://cygwin.com/install.html).

**2.** Open a Terminal Window.

**3.** Write these few characters at the command prompt:

```
dobre@Laptop ~
$ while true;
> do
>    du -hs .
> done
16M     .
16M     .
16M     .
16M     .
16M     .
16M     .
```

You may want to change the current home directory, represented above by the dot character (`.`) with any kind of directory you want to watch.

Welcome to the world of the *Bourne-Again* Shell-Scripting Environment!